# download zip file from github and push as new branch

Tags: html, css, git, github, sass

I download code from a branch github by pressing download zip button then I unzip the file and make some change. Is there anyway i can push that code to the same repo as a new branch?

Comment: If you have permissions sure u can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+downloaded+zip , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory

Answer (score 1):

Create new branch: `git checkout -b <name of branch>`

Go to new branch: `git checkout <name of branch>`

Check status of files: `git status`

Add any files that have been changed: `git add <files>`

Commit files: `git commit -m "<commit message>"`

Push to GitHub: `git push -u origin <name of branch>`

Comment: but its not in the same repo

Comment: Can you better explain what you mean?

Comment: i run git init and git remote add origin <github link> and add new branch as you suggest and it works